# Get Ajax content and filter it

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have this script that does ajax using jquery but i want to update with specific content, when I did it return undefined..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      url:'n.php',
      cache:false,
      type:"GET",
      success: function(data){
        $('.list-ball').html($(data).find(".count").html());
        console.log($(data).find(".count").html());
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what are you getting in `data`? Your code is hard to read please do formatting.

Comment: i used console log & i saw this

Comment: <div class="count"> 3 </div>

Comment: `<div class="count"> 3 </div>` is not a selector?

Comment: `find()` only finds descendants, if `.count` is at the root level, you'll have to use `$(data).filter(".count").html()` instead

Comment: thank u adeneo worked for mw

Answer (score 0):

Start with `console.log(data);`

This way you can see the returned data.
From there you can populate an element like so:

```
$("#myElement").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$(selector).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function that will replace content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // [url] [any valid css selector]
    $('.list-ball').load('n.php .count > *'); // Find `.count` content and place it instead of `.list-ball` content
});
```

If `.list-ball` element is not presented in DOM, than no ajax will be executed.

Comment: OP getting `<div class="count"> 3 </div>` in `data` and it is not selector. So I think issue is not in `.list-ball`.